# Spring REST/MVC & Security exception handling & filter chain requirements

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, spring-security

I've got a Spring REST application that is using Spring Security.  So far, I've been doing error handling using a `@ControllerAdvice` class which is great to handle all errors thrown during the MVC process.

However, all exceptions thrown by Spring Security (ex: `AccessDeniedException`) are not handled by MVC error handling as they never actually make it to the MVC components.  So if I want to handle Spring Security exceptions, I have to either add an `AccessDeniedHandler` or use a custom filter placed after the `EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER` (see [Spring Docs and Filter Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering)).

My main goal in handling my exceptions is that I want to return a consistent response to the client no matter the error being throw with pertinent information embedded in a JSON object (ex: Timestamp, error code, message, etc).

Is there a preferred technique for this kind of setup?  Or a better way of being able to centralize everything?  I love the simplicity of MVC error handling with `@ExceptionHandler`s but everything seems to push me towards using a custom filter and handle everything in one location.

On a related note, it seems to me that the [default FilterChain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-stack) that is generated by using namespace configuration is overkill for a REST application.  Is there a more appropriate configuration for a REST application?  (Ex: no need for the FORM_LOGIN_FILTER, REMEMBER_ME_FILTER, CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER, etc...).  Does anyone have a list of the filters that should be used in a REST application?  I cannot find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you right. I also had an issue to send a proper error message with json back to the client. I have written all (filter & provider) custom, because I authenticate via HTTPHeaderFields.
The error handling and sending proper messages back to the client has been the biggest issue. Short overview will follow:

At first I created custom delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint and AccesssDeniedHandler.
Snipp of secure config

```
...
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            // IMPORTANT: Add Filter after "ExceptionTranslation". 
            // If not AuthenticationException from Custom Filter or Custom Provider
            // will not be catched by AuthenticationEntryPoint.
            .addFilterAfter(httpClientFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
                // catch AuthenticationExeption and SecureToken with authenticated=false
                .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                // catch PermissionDenied Exeption e.g. missing in authorizeRequests()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new ClientRestAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
...
```

The ClientRestAccessDeniedHandler looks like this

```
public class ClientRestAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler{

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientRestAccessDeniedHandler.class);

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("Requered Role for this request is missing!");

        HTTPAuthenticationErrorSender.sendResponse(request, response, 
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    }
}
```

The Custom DelegationEntriyPoint looks very similar. Both call the HTTPAuthenticationErrorSender. It will send the HttpResponse generated by low level stuff :-).

```
public final class HTTPAuthenticationErrorSender {

    public static void sendResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication token) 
            throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{

        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HTTPAuthenticationErrorSender.class);

        if(!(token instanceof HTTPRestSecureToken)){
            if (token != null){
                response.sendError(403, "No valide AuthenticationToken found. Token instance of: "+token.getClass().toString());
                if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.debug("Send default HTTP Response 403. No HTTPRestSecureToken found. "
                            + "Token is instance of: "+token.getClass().getName());
            }
            else {
                response.sendError(403, "No valide AuthenticationToken found. Token is null");
                if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.debug("Send default HTTP Response 403. No HTTPRestSecureToken found. "
                            + "Token is null");
            }
            return;
        }

        HTTPRestSecureToken restToken = (HTTPRestSecureToken) token;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AuthenticationErrorResponse authErrorResponse =
                new AuthenticationErrorResponse(restToken.getAuthStatus().getErrorCode(),restToken.getAuthStatus().getDescription());
        String content = mapper.writeValueAsString(authErrorResponse);

        HTTPRestPrincipal principal = (HTTPRestPrincipal) token.getPrincipal();

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("AccessDenied for request: ["+principal.getFullURI()+"] clientID: ["+principal.getClientID()
                    + "] loginMail: ["+principal.getLoginMail()+"]");
            logger.debug("Send following json response: "+content);
        }

        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().print(content);
    }

}
```

To send proper Information I track status information in my custom SecureToken. The token will run throw secure chain filter and provider and will be filled up with information.

And yes I would say it is not very small for a common issue like this. But I couldn't find another way. The default Impl. are not detailed enough for my case.
I hope it will help a little or gives you a push in the right direction.

Comment: What do you have in your `httpClientFilter()`?